# NullPointerException - onPause()

Tags: java, android

This is goign to be very simple i expect to sort out and just me being a newbie going about in circles.

I have multiple tabs across my screen. The following code should read a text input and assign its value to Shared Preferences when another tab is selected. However, whenever i change to another tab my code fails with a NullPointerException - I believe i have tracked it down to the onPause() of the below code, and I believe it is because i am failing to pass the data within the variable correctly.

Any pointers appreciated!

```
package com.androidbook.epcsn;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class jobActivity extends Activity {   

public static final String SN_PREFERENCES  = "SiteNotePrefs";

SharedPreferences mPrefSettings;
String jobID;
String jobAddress ;
String jobPostcode ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    setContentView(R.layout.joblayout); 

    final SharedPreferences mPrefSettings = getSharedPreferences (SN_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

    initjobID();
    initjobaddress();
    initjobpostcode();
}

private void initjobpostcode() {
    EditText jobPostcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobPostcodeText);
}

private void initjobaddress() {
    EditText jobAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobAddressText);
}

private void initjobID() {
    EditText jobID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobIDText);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    String strjobID = jobID;
    String strjobAddress = jobAddress;
    String strjobPostcode = jobPostcode;

    Editor editor = mPrefSettings.edit();
    editor.putString("jobID", strjobID);
    editor.putString("jobAddress", strjobAddress);
    editor.putString("jobPostcode", strjobPostcode);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Comment: Please provide the actual error (the stacktrace). It should have linenumbers mentioned, so also tell us which line is the mentioned linenumber

Comment: Can you please show us the logtcat? and what is the exceptin exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set values to local variables in the `init` methods, not the class properties as intended, e.g.:

```
EditText jobID;

// Then later... it's clobberin' time.
private void initjobID() {
    EditText jobID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobIDText);
}
```

The property `jobID` is [shadowed](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/names.html#6.3.1) by the local `jobID` declared in the method.

*(Java conventions would name the method `initJobId`, and the property `jobId`).*

To set instance properties in the init methods, remove the local declarations and use this pattern:

```
EditText jobID;
private void initjobID() {
    jobID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobIDText);
}
```

Comment: @CornishDibley As do we all :)

Answer (score 0):

I imagine it's because you're setting

```
final SharedPreferences mPrefSettings = getSharedPreferences (SN_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

To a local variable instead of to a class member field.

Therefore the exception is probably at:

```
mPrefSettings.edit();
```

Because it is still null (never set in the `init` method).

Try changing it to:

```
mPrefSettings = getSharedPreferences (SN_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);
```

Also be careful with your other init methods eg `initjobID` as they are making the same mistake.

Change your class to:

```
package com.androidbook.epcsn;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

@SuppressWarnings("unused")
public class jobActivity extends Activity {   

public static final String SN_PREFERENCES  = "SiteNotePrefs";

SharedPreferences mPrefSettings;
String jobID;
String jobAddress ;
String jobPostcode ;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);          
    setContentView(R.layout.joblayout); 

    mPrefSettings = getSharedPreferences (SN_PREFERENCES, Context.MODE_WORLD_WRITEABLE);

    initjobID();
    initjobaddress();
    initjobpostcode();
}

private void initjobpostcode() {
    jobPostcode = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobPostcodeText);
}

private void initjobaddress() {
    jobAddress = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobAddressText);
}

private void initjobID() {
    jobID = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.jobIDText);
}

@Override
protected void onPause(){
    super.onPause();

    String strjobID = jobID;
    String strjobAddress = jobAddress;
    String strjobPostcode = jobPostcode;

    Editor editor = mPrefSettings.edit();
    editor.putString("jobID", strjobID);
    editor.putString("jobAddress", strjobAddress);
    editor.putString("jobPostcode", strjobPostcode);
    editor.commit();
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variables you set during `onCreate()` are not the same as those you declared at the class level. This is really a basic misunderstanding of how to declare and modify the contents of a variable in Java. See the following link, perhaps it will help you understand.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html